# os.system is not running gcloud command in gitpod environment

Tags: python, gcloud, gitpod

I trying to run gcloud command with help of python with following command in gitpod environment where Google Cloud SDK is already installed,

```
import os,sys
print (os.system("gcloud --version"))
```

But It is giving error that gcloud not found. I am not sure what exactly I am doing wrong!

Comment: Are you installing on Google Kubernetes Engine?

Comment: You may refer to this [link](https://github.com/gitpod-io/gitpod/blob/master/dev/image/Dockerfile#L118). Let me know if that helps!